# Media de los valores de una columna en Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Tengo el siguiente dataframe que leo desde un archivo csv y que todos los valores que se me interesan que se leen como string los paso a float:

```
import pandas as pd

lists = [
        ['Felix', 48, 40, 50],
        ['Manolo', 42, 41, 5],
        ['Felix', 8, 42, 53],
        [ 'Manolo', 0, 100, 96],
        [ 'Felix', 2, 110, 97]
    ]


df = pd.DataFrame(lists, columns = ['nombres', 'cant_A', 'cant_B', 'cant_C'])
df = df.set_index('nombres')
list_nom = ['Felix', 'Manolo']
list_cant = ['cant_A', 'cant_B', 'cant_C']
```

[image: DataFrame que leo y tengo][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve, hago una lista unicamente con los nombres del dataframe que no se repiten, es decir, esa lista ya la tengo metida en el código.

Me interesa guardar en un nuevo dataframe  el valor medio de las columnas 'cant_A' 'cant_B' y 'cant_C' solo para las filas en la que el índice 'nombres' sea el mismo. Me explico, quiero que me saque la media de 'cant_A' del nombre Felix, que sería (48+8+2)/3 = 19.33. Hay que partir de la premisa que no se el número de datos que va a tener 'cant_A' para el nombre 'Félix'.

Me gustaría que se pudiera implementar con un bucle `for` (pasando los nombres sin repetir que tengo en la list_nom) y posteriormente la función `.where()`, pero no se me ocurre nada. Es decir, siempre y cuando el nombre que pase desde la list_nom (p.ej 'Felix') sea igual que el index del dataframe (`df.index`; que previamente he asignado como 'nombres'), me haga la media de todos los valores que encuentre. Teniendo en cuenta que no voy a saber la magnitud de datos (nº de filas que sean Felix con el valor de la celda de la columna 'cant_A').
El nombre de las columnas del dataframe original también las tengo guardadas y las sé, por si sirviera de algo.

Posteriormente habría que hacer lo mismo con el nombre Manolo y los que hubiera en la "list_nom", por eso nombro el bucle `for`.

Al final el dataframe debería quedar algo así :

[image: DataFrame final de las medias de cada uno]

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que estás usando **Pandas** puedes usar su el método `groupby()` que está diseñado para ello, y es mucho más fácil que hacer bucles con condicionales.

El operador es similar (que no igual) al `GROUP BY` de SQL por ejemplo.

```
import pandas as pd

lists = [
        ['Felix', 48, 40, 50],
        ['Manolo', 42, 41, 5],
        ['Felix', 8, 42, 53],
        [ 'Manolo', 0, 100, 96],
        [ 'Felix', 2, 110, 97]
    ]

#Te he quitado la columna fecha, porque tienes 4 columnas no 5
df = pd.DataFrame(lists, columns = ['nombres', 'cant_A', 'cant_B', 'cant_C'])
df = df.set_index('nombres')
list_nom = ['Felix', 'Manolo']
list_cant = ['cant_A', 'cant_B', 'cant_C']

#Hayamos la media basandonos en el nombre
df.groupby(['nombres']).mean()
```

En el `groupby()` tienes que seleccionar la columna que quieres hacer la media, que en tu caso será **nombres**.

Esta operación lo que hará será agrupar todas las columnas por el tipo de "nombre" y luego hacer la media.

Te recomiendo ver la documentación de Pandas sobre el `groupby()`, es una de las  mejores funciones y más poderosas de pandas, que te quita mucho trabajo si sabes usarla. te dejo [aquí la documentación oficial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias Rubiales Alberto. He modificado mi pregunta borrando lo de fecha. En cuanto tenga tiempo le echo un vistazo e intento implementarlo. Si no, pondría un comentario volviendo a preguntar las dudas.

Comment: Me alegro de ayudar!! Si finalmente es la respuesta correcta, no te olvides de marcar mi respuesta como "respuesta correcta" esa es la mejor forma de agradecer en StackOverflow la ayuda :) .

Comment: Por supuesto. No te quepa duda que en cuanto tenga el tiempo de mirarlo te comento y te puntuo :) Un gran abrazo!